# Mysql query: fastest way to find users followed by or following another user

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables:

**Relationships**

`id`, `follower_id`, `followee_id`, `status`

**Users**

`id`, `name`, `email`

I want to find all users who are either following or followed by a specific user.

This is what I have so far but it is very slow:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    `users`.*
FROM
    `users`
        INNER JOIN
    `relationships` ON ((`users`.`id` = `relationships`.`follower_id`
        AND `relationships`.`followee_id` = 1)
        OR (`users`.`id` = `relationships`.`followee_id`
        AND `relationships`.`follower_id` = 1))
WHERE
    `relationships`.`status` = 'following'
ORDER BY `users`.`id`
```

**What I mean by slow**

I have one user who has roughly 600 followers and 600 following and it takes about 5 seconds for this query to run which seems insanely slow for those numbers!

The `explain` method shows the following:

```
+----+-------------+---------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+------+------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type | possible_keys                                                         | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                          |
+----+-------------+---------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+------+------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | relationships | ALL  | index_relationships_on_followed_id,index_relationships_on_follower_id | NULL | NULL    | NULL |  727 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort   |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users         | ALL  | PRIMARY                                                               | NULL | NULL    | NULL |  767 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x1) |
+----+-------------+---------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+------+------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: What indexes do you have defined on these tables?  What's the execution plan?

Comment: can you add `explain` result for this query?

Comment: Yep I'll add that. Actually I may have jumped the gun on stating it takes 5 seconds. I'm looking at a log from my production server which shows database access time being 5 seconds. I'm trying to reproduce this locally but it seems much faster than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try breaking this into two queries, with a `union`:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM `users` u INNER JOIN
     `relationships` r
      ON u.`id` = r.`follower_id` AND r.`followee_id` = 1
WHERE `r.`status` = 'following'
UNION
SELECT u.*
FROM `users` u INNER JOIN
     `relationships` r
      ON u.`id` = r.`followee_id` AND r.`follower_id` = 1
WHERE `r.`status` = 'following'
ORDER BY id;
```

This may be a case where a more complicated query has better performance.  These queries will also benefit from indexes:  `relationships(status, follower_id, followee_id)` and `relationships(status, followee_id, follower_id)`.

Comment: @MarkMurphy . . . That is why the query uses `union`.

Comment: on a side note, when I want to select just followers of a user are those indexes above sufficient for that or should I add another index `relationships(status, followee)` and maybe `relationships(status, follower)` when I want to get the reverse?

Comment: @MarkMurphy . . . If you have the three part index, the two-part indexes would be redundant.